# Openai Gym Box action space not bounding actions

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm using Keras RL2 to train DDPG agent on a custom openai gym environment. For the action space I'm using the line

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=100, shape=(18,), dtype=np.float32)
```

It completely ignores both the low and high values when training (has both negative values and values of over 200 at times). How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ActionNormalizer(gym.ActionWrapper):
"""Rescale and relocate the actions."""

def action(self, action: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Change the range (-1, 1) to (low, high)."""
    low = self.action_space.low
    high = self.action_space.high

    scale_factor = (high - low) / 2
    reloc_factor = high - scale_factor

    action = action * scale_factor + reloc_factor
    action = np.clip(action, low, high)

    return action

def reverse_action(self, action: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Change the range (low, high) to (-1, 1)."""
    low = self.action_space.low
    high = self.action_space.high

    scale_factor = (high - low) / 2
    reloc_factor = high - scale_factor

    action = (action - reloc_factor) / scale_factor
    action = np.clip(action, -1.0, 1.0)

    return action
```

this is a piece of code from https://github.com/MrSyee/pg-is-all-you-need, it scale input action to [-1, 1].

env = ActionNormalizer(gym.make("blablabla"))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).